# PostgreSQL: Create a foreign server and foreign table from within a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have a pretty long PLPGSQL function which does several things, one of them being to create a foreign server and foreign tables to contact tables from another database and insert rows in them. To do that, I have a fonction that looks like this:

```
-- Creates the foreign server and the foreign tables 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_foreign_ds() RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_foreign_server WHERE srvname = 'myserv') THEN
            CREATE SERVER myserv
            FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
            OPTIONS (host 'localhost',
                     dbname 'db',
                     port '5432');
            CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user SERVER myserv;
            PERFORM create_ds_foreign_table('table1');
            PERFORM create_ds_foreign_table('table2');
            PERFORM create_ds_foreign_table('table3');
            RAISE NOTICE 'Foreign tables created.';
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'Foreign server already existed';
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

When I invoke this function directly, everything is fine. But when I do it from within my main function, it does nothing (the foreign server and the foreign tables are not created) and the function later crashes because of that. The weird thing is that the notices in the function are printed, so the code is being executed but it does not create my server.

Comment: What is create_ds_foreign_table?

Comment: Perhaps the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @jjanes It is a function to create a foreign table on the server. I did that to avoid writing several times the same block of code to do it.